# YUI3 scrollView and mousewheel

Tags: yui, scrollview, mousewheel, yui3

I'm starting to work only with YUI3. I include component scrollView, but it did not work  mousewheel event, in the options I have not found how to turn on it. I would appreciate any help.

```
var scrollView = new Y.ScrollView({
    id: "scrollview",
    srcNode: '.scrollview-item',
    height: 375,
    flick: {
        minDistance: 10,
        minVelocity: 0.3,
        axis: "y"
    }
});
scrollView.render();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stumbled upon this as well, after some trial and error, I managed to get that working(note, that it is just plain scrolling, without an easing).

```
var DOM_MOUSE_SCROLL = 'DOMMouseScroll',
    fixArgs = function(args) {
        var a = Y.Array(args, 0, true), target;
        if (Y.UA.gecko) {
            a[0] = DOM_MOUSE_SCROLL;
            // target = Y.config.win;
        } else {
            // target = Y.config.doc;
        }

        if (a.length < 3) {
            // a[2] = target;
        } else {
            // a.splice(2, 0, target);
        }

        return a;
    };

Y.Env.evt.plugins.mousewheel = {
    on: function() {
        return Y.Event._attach(fixArgs(arguments));
    },

    detach: function() {
        return Y.Event.detach.apply(Y.Event, fixArgs(arguments));
    }
};
```

This is the YUI mousewheel event, but it's changed a bit. The biggest issue was, that originally, either the window or document elements, which makes no sense(for example when you mousewheel over the #myelement you want that to be the returned target..)

Bellow is the code used to initialize the ScrollView and the function that handles the mousewheel event:

```
// ScrollView
    var scrollView = new Y.ScrollView({
        id: "scrollview",
        srcNode: '#mycontainer',
        height: 490,
        flick: {
            minDistance:10,
            minVelocity:0.3,
            axis: "y"
        }
    });

    scrollView.render();

    var content = scrollView.get("contentBox"); 
    var scroll_modifier = 10; // 10px per Delta
    var current_scroll_y, scroll_to;

    content.on("mousewheel", function(e) {
        // check whether this is the scrollview container
        if ( e.currentTarget.hasClass('container') ) {
            current_scroll_y = scrollView.get('scrollY');
            scroll_to = current_scroll_y - ( scroll_modifier * e.wheelDelta );

            // trying to scroll above top of the container - scroll to start
            if ( scroll_to <= scrollView._minScrollY ) {
                // in my case, this made the scrollbars plugin to move, but I'm quite sure it's important for other stuff as well :)
                scrollView._uiDimensionsChange();
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView._minScrollY);
            } else if ( scroll_to >= scrollView._maxScrollY ) { // trying to scroll beneath the end of the container - scroll to end
                scrollView._uiDimensionsChange();
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, scrollView._maxScrollY);
            } else { // otherwise just scroll to the calculated Y
                scrollView._uiDimensionsChange();
                scrollView.scrollTo(0, scroll_to);
            };
            // if we have scrollbars plugin, flash the scrollbar
            if ( scrollView.scrollbars ) {
                scrollView.scrollbars.flash();
            };

            // prevent browser default behavior on mouse scroll
            e.preventDefault();
        };
    });
```

So basically that's how I managed to that, but my next challenge is to get the scrollbar work like regular scrollbar(when you drag it, the container should move correspondingly...)

Hope this helps anyone :)

Comment: Oh, yeah I forgot one thing - when using the scrollwheel, the container moves fine in FF and Opera, but is a bit slow in Chrome/Safari/IE(perhaps the Delta is different there, but I didn't bother to check that ^^ ).
To fix this, you could play with the `scroll_modifier`, checking the `wheelDelta`, the browser or whatever you decide